# mysql exclusive relation possibility

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Does mysql support exclusive relations?
E.g., I have 3 tables: CUSTOMER, FLAT, HOUSE. CUSTOMER is related to FLAR xor HOUSE.

If there possibility in mysql to use one relation for it?
Like, CUSTOMER would have 2 fields, one is related to object (FLAT or HOUSE), one is stored id.
I'd like to check on db level that this relation is not null. Don't want to create to foreign key to every table (FLAT and HOUSE).

Thanks.

added later:
sorry for not correct explanation. I don't want to create two different columns for each foreign key (to FLAT, to HOUSE). I suggest that there's something like exclusive relation and I create one column for id which can be foreign key to one of tables FLAT or HOUSE

Comment: This seems like a good reason to use a layer of abstraction. A Customer should have a Dwelling. A Dwellings can then link to the specific type such as Flat or House.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins thanks, George. OK, I have relation between CUSTOMER and DWELLING. But how can I check that one of relations from DWELLING (FLAT or HOUSE) is not null?

Answer (score 0):

```
create table flat (
    id int auto_increment,
    primary key (id)
);
create table house (
    id int auto_increment,
    primary key (id)
);
create table customer (
    id int auto_increment,
    flat_id int,
    house_id int,
    primary key (id),
    index flat_id (flat_id),
    index house_id (house_id),
    foreign key (flat_id) references flat(id) on delete cascade,
    foreign key (house_id) references house(id) on delete cascade
);
```

Comment: but this miss the FK to both tables, flat & house

Comment: @Vladimir Kovpak, thanks. But I want to use MTO relation from CUSTOMER to FLAT (HOUSE). So, if I delete the FLAT(HOUSE) object it will be deleted CUSTOMER objects which is related to it. There's no foreign key for your solving

Comment: @Luis Siquot wazz wrote: Don't want to create to foreign key to every table (FLAT and HOUSE).

Comment: @VladimirKovpak sorry for not correct explanation. I don't want to create two different columns for each foreign key (to FLAT, to HOUSE). I suggest that there's something like exclusive relation and I create one column for id which can be foreign key to one of tables FLAT or HOUSE

Comment: @wazz Is last example closer to your desires?)

Comment: @VladimirKovpak thanks for your help. But unfortunately I want to find decision where I can use cascade delete for relation. So when I delete value in FLAT the related value to it from CUSTOMER  will be deleted cascade.

Comment: to buid constraint at table flat|house you should have foreign key to customer `constraint customer foreign key (customer_id) references customer (id) on delete cascade`, and it is not relation MTO...

Comment: @VladimirKovpak sorry, didn't understand about "not relation MTO". If I try to use exclusive arc with two fk it would be like `CONSTRAINT FK_CUSTOMER_FLAT FOREIGN KEY (CUSTOMER_FLAT_ID) REFERENCES FLAT (ID) ON DELETE cascade` in CUSTOMER table creation script. It's many to one, many customers for one FLAT

Comment: @wazz in table flat|house you should know customer, because how mysql will now what to delete on cascading...

Comment: @VladimirKovpak don't understand, sorry. I have tables FLAT and HOUSE. I have table CUSTOMER with 2 fields, the are FK to FLAT and HOUSE. If I smt delete from FLAT, the linked customers will be deleted.

Comment: @wazz maybe i incorrect understand you have relation: one customer - many flats, or one flat - many customers?

Comment: @VladimirKovpak thanks for trying to understand me. One house(flat) has several customers.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it'd be better to use base parent table for my problem .

Thanks for George Cummins comment.
I can create DWELLING table with only id field.

```
CREATE TABLE DWELLING (
    ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
  , PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

And add FK to CUSTOMER, FLAT, HOUSE tables.

```
CREATE TABLE FLAT (
    ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
  , DWELLING_ID INT NOT NULL
  , PRIMARY KEY (ID)
  , CONSTRAINT FK_DWELLING_FLAT FOREIGN KEY (DWELLING_ID) REFERENCES DWELLING (ID) ON DELETE cascade
);
CREATE TABLE HOUSE (
    ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
  , DWELLING_ID INT NOT NULL
  , PRIMARY KEY (ID)
  , CONSTRAINT FK_DWELLING_HOUSE FOREIGN KEY (DWELLING_ID) REFERENCES DWELLING (ID) ON DELETE cascade
);
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER (
    ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
  , DWELLING_ID INT NOT NULL
  , PRIMARY KEY (ID)
  , CONSTRAINT FK_DWELLING_CUSTOMER FOREIGN KEY (DWELLING_ID) REFERENCES DWELLING (ID) ON DELETE cascade
);
```

After that if the flat or house need to be deleted, I have to delete relating DWELLING object.

I used this http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/practical-object-oriented-models-in-sql, slide 29

If you're not agree with me please add a comment. I'd be glad to see your comments.

Thanks.